# Creating an array that creates smaller variable arrays within itself based on the size of a DateTime interval object php

Tags: php

This is somewhat basic but one of my first PHP projects and I'm stuck. I need to create something that will iterate through a series of DateTime objects and sort them into groups based on the interval of time between each object, with the end goal being to average data associated with these groups of dates (just focusing on how to group the data in this post). If the DateTime objects are more than 1 day apart, then they need to be in a separate sub-group but still a part of the larger list of dates.

I have been able to create DateInterval objects from the DateTime objects. Below is an example of two DateTime objects pulled from a larger list of dates and the corresponding DateInterval generated from the amount of time between the two`

```
[4] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-04-21 12:50:53.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => America/Denver
    )

[5] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2015-04-18 12:50:53.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => America/Denver
    )


    `[9] => DateInterval Object
    (
        [y] => 2
        [m] => 0
        [d] => 3
        [h] => 0
        [i] => 0
        [s] => 0
        [weekday] => 0
        [weekday_behavior] => 0
        [first_last_day_of] => 0
        [invert] => 1
        [days] => 734
        [special_type] => 0
        [special_amount] => 0
        [have_weekday_relative] => 0
        [have_special_relative] => 0
    )`
```

Is there a way I could create some sort of array that holds subgroups of date objects in their own array that are sorted based on the size of their intervals? I illustrated the structure of what I'm thinking below.

```
Array [
       Array [
                [date1],
                [date2],
                [date3]
             ]
       Array [ 
                [date4],
                [date5],
             ]
       Array [
                [date6]
             ]
       ]
```

Comment: I answered based on my initial understanding of the question, but I'm afraid it may be incomplete because I'm not sure what you meant by "sorted based on the size of their intervals". Could you please provide an example output with actual dates to clarify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, sort your array of dates (if they aren't already sorted).

```
sort($dates);
```

Then keep track of the previous item as you iterate the array. If the number of days in the diff interval exceeds your threshold then increment the key used to define the groups in the result array.

```
$i = 0;
$previous = null;

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    if ($previous && $date->diff($previous)->days > 1) {
        $i++;
    }
    $groups[$i][] = $date;
    $previous = $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that solved my problem, which was made from a slight modification of @Don'tPanic's code.

```
$incrementKey = 0;
foreach ($datesIntervalArray as $d) {

    if ($d->days > 1) {
        $incrementKey++;
    }

    $groupsOfVisits[$incrementKey][] = $d;

`
```